# Access form object from another cs file

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to display image in `PictureBox` and text in `Label` in from from another cs file i do this code but didn't work correctly any help?!

```
Form1 d = new Form1();
d.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\a\Desktop\tuio.jpg");
                d.label1.Text = "A" + "APPLE";
                d.Show();
```

when the form open doesn't respond and the program stoped.

Comment: the image didn't display and the program stop working when remove this lines of code work correctly

Comment: @user3306375 try put a image path (string) parameter on form1 constructor and pass the value from another file then you can set the image property from the same form. also try to get the error when using the current code.

Comment: It works fine on my box.   Are you sure the path and name of the image are correct?

Comment: @SteveWellens yes the path and name are correct

Comment: Then you are doing something else that you haven't shared in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the PictureBox or the Label from the original instance by using the above code because instead you've created a new instance and modified that one instead. What I'd do is change the `PictureBox` from `public` to `public static` and do the same with the `Label`. Then, if in any code you've referred to either the Label or the PictureBox using `this.`, simply remove this and then the PictureBox and Label should be accessible from any class. You would access it by using `Form1.picturebox1.Image = [...]` and `Form1.label1.Text = [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the modifiers property of your picturebox and label to public and if your Picture path is correct, then calling

```
d.ShowDialog();
```

should work.

Comment: I set the modifiers and edit my code but didn't work !